# Алгоритм - метод итераций C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм

По моей функции этот метод должен посчитать ноль функции = 3.75, а он считает только 3, причем на любых интервалах. Функция: `f(x)=(x - 48) * (x - 48) + (sin (x - 48))`
Вот график функции: 
[image]

Код алгоритма:

```
double f4(double x) 
{
    return   ((1/8) * (sin (x - (30/8))) + (30/8));
}

double iter(double a, double b, double eps)
{
    int k=0;
    double x0,xk;
    x0=(a+b)/2;

    do
   {
    xk=f4(x0);
    if (fabs(xk-x0)<eps) break;
    else x0=xk;

   }
   while (fabs(a-x0)>eps && fabs(b-x0)>eps);
   cout << "Ноль функции = "<<xk<<"\n";
   return xk;
}
```

Comment: Возможно, это Вам поможет: http://neerc.ifmo.ru/mediawiki/index.php/Вещественный двоичный поиск

Comment: что делает функция f4()?

Comment: f4() добавила код

Comment: это не поиск, здесь нужно найти ноль функции, я читала про алгоритм итераций, но там используется какое-то φ(x) : "Для применения этого метода исходное уравнение f(x)=0 должно быть приведено к виду x=φ(x) "

Смотрела здесь: http://www.intuit.ru/department/calculate/intromathmodel/4/2.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Из-за того, что у вас в функции f4 все константы целочисленные, она всегда возвращает 3.
Правильно было бы так:

```
double f4(double x) 
{
    return   ((1.0/8.0) * (sin (x - (30.0/8.0))) + (30.0/8.0));
}
```

а еще лучше:

```
double f4(double x) 
{
    return   0.125 * sin(x - 3.75) + 3.75;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все получилось.